# Using NS http.request to send a curl

Tags: http, firebase, push-notification, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am attempting to use the nativescript HTTP.request to send a curl for firebase push notifications. I have tested the curl and it works however I am getting a bad request error when i try to send it via http.request.

Here is the curl code (my key has been substituted for a variable for privacy reasons)

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=MyKey" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"notification\":{\"title\": \"My title\", \"text\": \"My text\", \"sound\": \"default\"}, \"data\":{\"foo\":\"bar\"}, \"priority\": \"High\", \"to\":\"d1LHpypPxA0:APA91bHG4HlZQnb7F_BkZAZYHv1MM00FhNbsONMhsLRB-U4p3As3C0Pp_8ALqQFusOOkgdSHZUlOfHbtt6qXU8pzCnjC-ozfMU3vTqjY0iy90XDvGHkDt0qw1w2wnr73PjFqViHEGONH\"}"
```

here is my http.request

```
http.request({
                    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'key=MyKey','Content-Type': 'application/json'} ,
                    content: {
                        "notification": {
                            "title": "testingtesting",
                            "text": "some text",
                            "sound": "default",
                            "priority": "High"
                        }
                    },
                        data: { "foo": "bar" },
                        to: "d1LHpypPxA0:APA91bHG4HlZQnb7F_BkZAZYHv1MM00FhNbsONMhsLRB-U4p3As3C0Pp_8ALqQFusOOkgdSHZUlOfHbtt6qXU8pzCnjC-ozfMU3vTqjY0iy90XDvGHkDt0qw1w2wnr73PjFqViHEGONH"


                }).then((response) => {
                    //HttpResult = response.content.toJSON();
                    console.log('----------------------------------------------------');
                    console.log(response.content);
                }, (e) => {
                    console.log("Error occurred " + e);
                });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like `headers` is wrong.  According to the docs, it should be in JSON format (not sure if it should be an array or object though).  Also, why not use Angular's HTTP functionality if you're using it?

Comment: @rrjohnson85 i have adjusted the code to fir this format

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you still need to `JSON.stringify()` the content.  Take a look at the HTTP tests in Github and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, this is the code that worked. I had some issues with formatting, I hope this helps someone in the future!

```
var HttpResult;
                http.request({
                    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'key=MyKey', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    content: JSON.stringify({
                        "notification": {
                            "title": "testingtesting",
                            "text": "some text",
                            "sound": "default",
                            "priority": "High"
                        },
                         'data': { "foo": "bar" },
                        'to': "d1LHpypPxA0:APA91bHG4HlZQnb7F_BkZAZYHv1MM00FhNbsONMhsLRB-U4p3As3C0Pp_8ALqQFusOOkgdSHZUlOfHbtt6qXU8pzCnjC-ozfMU3vTqjY0iy90XDvGHkDt0qw1w2wnr73PjFqViHEGONH"
                    })
                }).then((response) => {
                    //HttpResult = response.content.toJSON();
                    console.log('----------------------------------------------------');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                }, (e) => {
                    console.log("Error occurred " + JSON.stringify(e));
                });
```